# AdColony mediation no fill from ad source

Tags: android, admob, adcolony, mobile-ad-mediation

When I add following line of code to configure AdColony ads, I am getting "No fill from ad source" in admob testing suite.

I am writing below code before *MobileAds.initialize* and before loading any ads.

But, if remove below code, ads are working fine. But for me it is necessary to pass some extra information to adcolony before loading ads.

```
    val options = AdColonyAppOptions()
            .setKeepScreenOn(true)
            .setGDPRConsentString(adColonyConsent)
            .setGDPRRequired(adColonyGDPRRequired)

    AdColony.configure(this, options, getString(R.string.adcolony_app_id), getString(R.string.adcolony_zone_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the following:

```
        val appOptions = AdColonyMediationAdapter.getAppOptions()
        appOptions.keepScreenOn = true
        appOptions.gdprRequired = requiredBoolean (true/false)
        appOptions.gdprConsentString = consentString ("0"/"1")

        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.ADMOB_APP_ID))
```